# This code taken from microsoft is only copying the text files in the main directory not sub-directories

Tags: c#, copy, subdirectory

Taken from:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571.aspx

I've modified it to copy files, but even when I had it exactly as microsofts example, it still is ignoring the text file I placed in a subdirectory as a test...I'm dying to know what is going on here since I thought "SearchOption.AllDirectories" took care of that...

```
        {
            string sourceDirectory = @"C:\Users\root\Desktop\bms 2013\bms 2013";
            string archiveDirectory = @"C:\Users\root\Desktop\test";

            try
            {
                var txtFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

                foreach (string currentFile in txtFiles)
                {
                    string fileName = currentFile.Substring(sourceDirectory.Length + 1);
                    File.Copy(currentFile, Path.Combine(archiveDirectory, fileName));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
             //   Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Does the subdirectory already exist at the target destination?  Does File.Copy() create the target directory if it doesn't exist? (I doubt it).

Comment: You are right!  I was thinking it would just lump everything into the main directory.  Now that I know the issue, I can work on that next, thanks!